# Select in MYSQL -- Select all the records

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a function like below:

```
public function select($id=null) {
    $query = "select * from press_releases where id = {$id}";

    $results = $this->db->query($query);

    return $results;
}
```

If no `$id` is specified during function invoke, I want to return all the records but I think `NULL` default value is not a good option for that. What should I do instead of `NULL` to retrieve all the records other than using a another query which doesn't specify the id field in the where section.

Thanks...

Comment: There are always people who think they are clever and downvote others' questions...

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you have to understand than soemone does not downvote because he thinks he's clever. I guess that everyone who comes at this site, either asking or answering, thinks he's quite clever. Downvote means he thinks that the question is not clear or it can not be useful or that it's not obvious that the OP searched a bit or tried something before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$query = "select * from press_releases";
if (!empty($id))
{
   $query .= "where id = {$id}";
}
```

If `$id` is an integer, I would use:

```
$id = (int) $id;
if ($id > 0)
...
```

Either way I would make sure `$id` is safe to use.

Comment: I like this answer, although similar to what I implemented.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
$query = "select * from press_releases where id = {$id} OR {$id} IS NULL";
```

Answer (score -1):

You could replace the where operator to LIKE, as in

```
$query = "select * from press_releases where id LIKE '{$id}'";
```

and change the default value to the '%', but I don't like this solution for efficiency reasons.

You should do that only if you absolutely need to keep the query as you written. Otherwise change the query to append the where condition only if the `$id` parameter is given. That would be the right solution.

Comment: You're right, I written it from scratch because it asked to not change the query. I'm going to update my answer with a correct one.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT id FROM press_releases